# Minimum number of distinct variables needed for lambda calculus to be Turing-complete?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, lambda-calculus

Suppose you start with your everyday vanilla untyped lambda calculus, but restrict the alphabet to a finite number of variables. What is the minimum number of variables you need for Turing-completeness?

For example, if you only have $\Sigma=\{x\}$, it seems like the number of things you can do with $\lambda x . M$ will be heavily curtailed, since every variable is bound to its nearest $\lambda$, so you can only work with one variable at a time.

However, since $\Sigma=\{x,y,z\}$ is sufficient to form the $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ [combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), that immediately seems like it must be Turing-complete.

**My question: what are the limitations of lambda calculus when restricted to one or two variables?** Do they correspond to other well-known computational categories, like having the same expressive power as some class of automaton? I would expect two variables to be strictly more powerful than one, but I can't seem to find anything on either case by searching.

Comment: Yes, three variables are definitely enough, for the reason you have. No idea about fewer variables.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1007/11560586_32) proving that for Turing completeness, you need a minimum of three variables.

This still leaves open the question of what, if anything, one- and two-variable systems are computationally equivalent to.